# How to make Gitlab CI support Asp.net Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, gitlab-ci

I have the following simple pipeline defined for my Asp.Net Core project:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

stages:
    - build
    - test

variables:
    test: "Testing"

before_script:
    - "cd *my folder with projects*"
    - "dotnet restore"

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - "dotnet build"

test:
    stage: test
    script: 
        - "dotnet test"
```

When I tried to run it against my project, it failed with an exit code 1 and a message:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.803/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5):
>   error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET
>   Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of
>   the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Do you have your `global.json` set to use a Microsoft .NET Core SDK that targets 3.1?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I don't have this file in my project. Where can I find more info about it?

Comment: you’ll want to put this file at the root of your solution directory, with the version of the .net SDK as a value inside that file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json

Comment: @GeorgeStocker thank you for your reply! I put the file in my solution directory as you said and I specified the Sdk version to be 3.1.101. Now that it's done, gitlab says that this version was simply not found and referred me to this page: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409 .

Comment: The issue I see now is that your .YML file specifes a .NET Runtime to use; not an SDK. They're different. You need to use the correct image for your CI build. To build an application, you need the .NET Microsoft SDK image; which in this case line #1 of your YAML would be: `microsoft/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1`

Comment: This indeed makes sense. I edited the file, but now it throws this error: "Error response from daemon: pull access denied for microsoft/dotnet/core/sdk, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' (executor_docker.go:188:0s)"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try setting the image to

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
```

That should use the .NET Core 3.1 SDK

Comment: Bear in mind that since the release of .NET 5, the repository path changed to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1`. Here is a link to the rename anouncement: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/2375